# Python vs Julia autocorrelation

Tags: python, julia

I am trying to do autocorrelation using Julia and compare it to Python's result. How come they give different results?

Julia code

```
using StatsBase

t = range(0, stop=10, length=10)
test_data = sin.(exp.(t.^2))

acf = StatsBase.autocor(test_data)
```

gives

```
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
  1.0                   
  0.13254954979179642   
 -0.2030283419321465    
  0.00029587850872956104
 -0.06629381497277881   
  0.031309038331589614  
 -0.16633393452504994   
 -0.08482388975165675   
  0.0006905628640697538 
 -0.1443650483145533
```

Python code

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0,10,10)
test_data = np.sin(np.exp(t**2))

acf_result = acf(test_data)
```

gives

```
array([ 1.        ,  0.14589844, -0.10412699,  0.07817509, -0.12916543,
       -0.03469143, -0.129255  , -0.15982435, -0.02067688, -0.14633346])
```

Comment: Print the test data in both cases

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is because your `test_data` is different:

Python:

```
array([ 0.84147098, -0.29102733,  0.96323736,  0.75441021, -0.37291918,
        0.85600145,  0.89676529, -0.34006519, -0.75811102, -0.99910501])
```

Julia:

```
[0.8414709848078965, -0.2910273263243299, 0.963237364649543, 0.7544102058854344,
 -0.3729191776326039, 0.8560014512776061, 0.9841238290665676, 0.1665709194875013,
 -0.7581110212957692, -0.9991050130774393]
```

This happens because you are taking `sin` of enormous numbers. For example, with the last number in `t` being 10, `exp(10^2)` is ~2.7*10^43. At this scale, floating point inaccuracies are about 3*10^9. So if even the least significant bit is different for Python and Julia, the `sin` value will be way off.

In fact, we can inspect the underlying binary values of the initial array `t`. For example, they differ in the third last value:

Julia:

```
julia> reinterpret(Int, range(0, stop=10, length=10)[end-2])
4620443017702830535
```

Python:

```
>>> import struct
>>> s = struct.pack('>d', np.linspace(0,10,10)[-3])
>>> struct.unpack('>q', s)[0]
4620443017702830536
```

We can indeed see that they disagree by exactly one machine epsilon. And if we use Julia take `sin` of the value obtained by Python:

```
julia> sin(exp(reinterpret(Float64, 4620443017702830536)^2))
-0.3400651855865199
```

We get the same value Python does.

Answer (score 10):

Just to expand a bit on the answer (adding as an answer as it is too long for a comment). In Julia you have the following:

```
julia> t = collect(range(0, stop=10, length=10))
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
  0.0               
  1.1111111111111112
  2.2222222222222223
  3.3333333333333335
  4.444444444444445 
  5.555555555555555 
  6.666666666666667 
  7.777777777777778 
  8.88888888888889  
 10.0               

julia> t .- [10*i / 9 for i in 0:9]
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
```

while in Python:

```
>>> t = np.linspace(0,10,10)
>>> t - [10*i/9 for i in range(10)]
array([0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 8.8817842e-16,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00])
```

and you see that the 8-th number in Python is an inaccurate approximation of `70/9`, while in Julia in this case you get the sequence of closest approximations of `10*i/9` using `Float64`.

So it would seem that because the original sequences differ you the rest follows what @Jakob Nissen commented.

However the things are not that simple. As `exp` functions in Julia and Python differ a bit in what they produce. See Python:

```
>>> from math import exp
>>> from mpmath import mp
>>> mp.dps = 1000
>>> float(mp.exp((20/3)**2) - exp((20/3)**2))
-1957.096392544307
```

while in Julia:

```
julia> setprecision(1000)
1000

julia> Float64(exp(big((20/3)^2)) - exp((20/3)^2))
2138.903607455693

julia> Float64(exp(big((20/3)^2)) - nextfloat(exp((20/3)^2)))
-1957.096392544307
```

(you can check that `(20/3)^2` is the same `Float64` both in Julia and Python).

So in this case with `exp` Python is slightly more accurate than Julia. Therefore even fixing `t` (which is easy by using a comprehension in Python instead of `linspace`) will not make the ACF to be equal.

All in all the conclusion is what @Jakob Nissen commented for such large values the results will be strongly influenced by the numerical inaccuracies.